# How to create the below effects im flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to create the below effects. I used the `VerticalCardPager` and made small changes to it to make the width of all the cards equal. But I couldn't get the desired result. Can someone give any idea on achieving this?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the question. Also add what you tried, where you got stuck, provide a minimal example on https://dartpad.dev/, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The library VerticalCardPager needs improvement as it runs loop for all children and calculate stuff even when they are not being drawn.

I tried different approach and got it working with following code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Pager Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _upcomingPage = 0;
  final _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.6);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> titles = [
      "RED",
      "YELLOW",
      "BLACK",
      "CYAN",
      "BLUE",
      "GREY",
    ];

    final List<Widget> images = [
      Container(
        color: Colors.pink[800],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.purple[800],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.deepOrange[800],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.indigo[800],
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green[800],
      ),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
              if ((details.primaryVelocity ?? 0) > 0) {
                _upcomingPage = (_pageController.page?.toInt() ?? 0) - 1;
                _pageController.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.linear);
              } else if ((details.primaryVelocity ?? 0) < 0) {
                _upcomingPage = (_pageController.page?.toInt() ?? 0) + 1;
                _pageController.nextPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.linear);
              }
              if (_upcomingPage < 0) {
                _upcomingPage = 0;
              }
              if (_upcomingPage == images.length) {
                _upcomingPage = images.length - 1;
              }
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: PageView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: _pageController,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final Alignment align;
                final double heightFactor;
                if (index < _upcomingPage) {
                  align = Alignment.bottomCenter;
                  heightFactor = 0.3;
                } else if (index > _upcomingPage) {
                  align = Alignment.topCenter;
                  heightFactor = 0.3;
                } else {
                  align = Alignment.center;
                  heightFactor = 1;
                }

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                  child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    alignment: align,
                    child: AnimatedFractionallySizedBox(
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      heightFactor: heightFactor,
                      alignment: align,
                      child: Stack(children: [
                        // modify your items here.
                        images[index],
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            titles[index],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: images.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Video: https://youtu.be/dOg-ZvPrWSY

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way that we can increase the widgets visible at one time like the selected item and the items that are not selected.

Comment: That will require different approach. Do you have design explaining it?

Comment: As in the video you shared there is a space left until the first element(RED) meets. I need to remove this space. I tried several things like increasing card size and increasing viewport fraction and one of them is trying to show several unselected items like in verticlePageReader.  But my initial goal is to remove the space that I mention when scroll to the top of the list.

Comment: Is there any way that we can satisfy this requirements

Comment: Got it. I think the animation shared in the question also has same thing. I missed it. I will try to implement it.